# SSRS - Using RunningValue vertically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am running a report on SSRS where 2 of the columns are running value.

Before it was like:

[image]

SO i was running the report by each code at once.

I changed it to allow multiple codes to be shown in the report (Grouping by Code) and it gave me the below:

[image]

As you can see, its doing running value horizontally.

I want it to do it vertically by each code like below:

[image]

MAYBE USING THE COLUMN GROUP AS SCOPE WILL WORK? I AM NOT SURE HOW TO USE COLUMN GROUPS IN SCOPE. ANY IDEAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

Using the column group as scope works. I was using `Nothing` before as the scope. THen tried using the group in square brackets until i realised it needs to be passed as a string like "groupName"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by writing custom code - 
Go to Report Properties and write code

```
public corder as integer
Function GetcOrder(order as integer) as integer
corder =corder + order 
Return corder 
End Function
```

[image]

Give a Name to Order text box

Next write an expression to calculate cumulative order value by calling function written in first step

[image]

preview output

[image]

Repeat the same step for rest of cumulative values .. please make sure to define public variable like

```
public corder as integer
```

All the Best!